# Crop image in android Nougat

Tags: android, image, crop

I have update my phone to android nougat and the function crop suddenly not working. In Marshmallow worked perfectly. 
This is my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "multas.com.usj.multaszgz"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile project(':tess-two-release')
compile files('libs/androidjhlabs.jar')
//Pestañas
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.7.jar')
compile project(path: ':openCVLibrary310')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
compile 'org.codepond:wizardroid:1.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And this is the code for crop:

```
  private void crop(){
try {

  Log.v("OCRActivity", "HA LLEGADO AL CROP: "+takeStoragePermissionGranted());
  File file = new File(path);
  Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

  Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
  intent.setDataAndType(outputFileUri, "image/*");
  intent.putExtra("crop", true);
  //intent.putExtra("outputX",bm.getWidth());
  //intent.putExtra("outputY", bm.getHeight());
  intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
  intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
  intent.putExtra("scale", true);
  intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
  Log.v("OCRActivity", "HA LLEGADO ");

  startActivityForResult(intent, PIC_CROP);

}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
  //display an error message
  String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  toast.show();
}catch(Exception e){
  Log.e("OCRActivity", "crop():"+e.getMessage());
}

   }
```

I dont detect any error in console, but in onActivityOnResult return the resultcode = 0 when it should be 1...
I dont know what happen with nougat, with marshmallow the same code it worked...

Any solution please?

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: Ok, Thanks!. So, my question now is... Can I include an AOSP camera in android nougat? I wouldnt like import a library for croping because this app its for me, not for any phone or user.

Comment: Finally I have installed this camera .apk (http://www.qbking77.com/apps-games/download-the-camera-and-live-wallpaper-from-google-play-edition-devices/)and it has been perfect! Thanks CommonsWare for the information about crop intent. In all sites that I see, the information appear like if camera.action.crop was an android instruction...

Comment: Can please give your solution?.I have same problem.

Comment: Crop intent use some app installed in the phone that it was created with AOSP. Original Camera in nougat dont use AOSP, for that reason the best way to resolve is install one app like http://www.qbking77.com/apps-games/download-the-camera-and-live-wallpaper-from-google-play-edition-devices/ compatible. That it was the only solution for me...

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function in my android project.
Hopefully its help you.

// FUNCTION FOR CROPING IMAGE

```
 private void croppingIMG() {
    imageSelect = true;
    final ArrayList cropOptions = new ArrayList();
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    List list = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    int size = list.size();
    if (size == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cann't find image croping app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else {
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 512);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 512);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        //TODO: don't use return-data tag because it's not return large image data and crash not given any message
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(outPutFile));

        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i   = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = (ResolveInfo) list.get(0);
            i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            startActivityForResult(i, CROPING_CODE);
        } else {

            Intent i   = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = (ResolveInfo) list.get(0);
            i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            startActivityForResult(i, CROPING_CODE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Android -N Passing file:// URIs outside the package domain may leave the receiver with an unaccessible path. Therefore, attempts to pass a file:// URI trigger a FileUriExposedException.

For details go through this [article](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en).

One thing also note that you will have to add output uri to your crop intent while selecting image from gallery for API >= 24 like,

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(YOUR_FILE_PATH));